# Как определить макрос BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL?

Tags: c++, boost

Что значит определить макрос BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL и как это сделать? Я пытаюсь использовать библиотеку ozo зависящую от буста, но выводится следующая ошибка компиляции :

> #error "OZO needs BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL to be defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропишите в .cpp файле следующий код:

```
#define BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL 1
```

Должно помочь.